# Push Notifications don't work on iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-arrow

I have an issue with push notifications using Arrow.

In development mode, everything is fine, registrations are correctly send and notifications are well received on both android and iOs.

In production, no problem for registration. Each device is stocked into Arrow and I can see it in my account with its device_token.

When I try to send a notification to users, only Android users receive them. Nothing on iOs. I took an Apple Push Services certificate and transformed it into P12 file.

Here is my registration code :

```
var Cloud = require("ti.cloud");
 // Subscribes the device to the 'news_alerts' channel
 // Specify the push type as either 'android' for Android or 'ios' for iOS
    Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribeToken({
        device_token: deviceToken,
        channel: 'news_alerts',
        type: Ti.Platform.name == 'android' ? 'android' : 'ios'
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            Ti.API.info('Subscribed');
        } else {
            Ti.API.info('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}
```

Subscriptions are OK, Development mode is ok, Android on production is OK...

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you use something like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apn-tester-free/id626590577?mt=12 to verify if the app-side of things is set up correctly?

Comment: You can use this [online APNs tester tool](http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/)

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator
I tried the application.
`-Connected to server gateway.push.apple.com 
-Set SSL connection 
-Set peer domain name gateway.push.apple.com 
-Keychain Opened  
-Certificate  data  for Apple Push Services: com.pinkandribs.seeoo initialized successfully 
-Sec Identity created 
-Client certificate created 
-Connected 
-Token: <200a5dd5 10b07aa2 33c56f85 d721eadf 85139532 6b2ab259 9ba1f352 9d25f9b2> 
-Written 92 bytes sending data to gateway.push.apple.com:2195 
-Disconnected from server gateway.push.apple.com:2195 `

Comment: Did you receive the notification?

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator No, nothing :(

Comment: And you did use the correct device token? Then looking at logs the cert seems ok so there must be an issue with the provisioning or entitlements of the iOS app. When you install the app are there any logs when you connect Xcode while doing so?

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator I'm not sure if the device token is correct. I've downloaded the production app in the App Store, accept to receive PN, and I went to Arrow log on Appcelerator to see my Device token. I did another test with APN tester and nothing. I think my device token is not correct but how can I check this ?

Comment: If after accepting PN that deviceToken popped up on Arrow then that token is correct. Is there anything significant visible in the logs (connect device and open Xcode > Devices) while you go through these steps?

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator I tried to re-create CSR file with new apple WWDR and make a new CER file with it. Then I tried APN free tester and I correctly receive notification. After that, I created the P12 file and uploaded it in my arrow dashboard. I don't receive any notification (on android it works fine). I don't understand...

Comment: I think it would be best if you'd contact support@appcelerator.com so they can dive into your specific account and help you debug this.

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator - No device logs in xCode device. I will try to review my app with a new provisionning file. Maybe the WWDR was not correctly set. Any other idea ?

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator Ok, thank you.